# Vulkan - wrong images used by samplers when using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, vulkan

I'm currently developing graphic engine using Vulkan and I'm stuck on nasty problem with texture samplers when trying to render scene in parallel. Problem is that when I use single thread to do so, every texture is rendered fine but under multiple threads the textures seem to occasionally switch which produces graphic glitches (examples below). I tried many things like very restrictive synchronization, new samplers per texture, new descriptor sets per worker but none of those changed anything and I'm pretty much lost what to do more. Maybe someone have some vague idea what could be a culprit here?

Here is an example when everything works fine in single thread:
[image: Single thread - no glitches]
And here is example where few textures are different like empty spaces or strange tree
[image: Multiple threads - mismatched textures]

If you would want to check out the code here's repository ( branch: FirstOracle-0.5.5 ):
https://github.com/n1t4chi/FirstStory

Rendering is mostly performed in this class:
https://github.com/n1t4chi/FirstStory/blob/FirstOracle-0.5.5/FirstOracle/FirstOracle-Engine/src/main/java/com/firststory/firstoracle/vulkan/physicaldevice/rendering/VulkanRenderStageWorker.java

To run, Java 12 is necessary with below run configuration:
Module: FirstOracle-Engine
Main class: com.firststory.firstoracle.templates.optimisation.App3D
VM arguments:
-Doptimised=false
--enable-preview
-DRenderingFrameworkClassName=com.firststory.firstoracle.vulkan.VulkanFrameworkProvider
-Dvulkan.threads=[number of threads to render with, 1 for single thread or 2 for multi]

Comment: What does "restrictive synchronization" mean in Your case? Does these glitches occur even if there are multiple threads, but in fact they are executed one after another? Are descriptor pools shared across threads? How do You submit command buffers to a queue? Are there any errors reported by Validation Layers?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, I tried making threads work only one at the time with same result. I also tried creating descriptor pools in same thread they are used but I also did not see any improvement. Primary command buffers are built in worker threads and returned to main thread where they are all submitted in single call. They are also synchronized with semaphores so that primary buffers are executed in order. Validation layers do not report any errors.

Comment: So maybe it is a driver bug? Did You try running You app on a different hardware? Oh, and I see I made a mistake - I meant "command pools" not "descriptor pools". Are command pools shared across threads? Or is there a separate command pool for each thread? (I expect You have a separate pool per thread, but just to be clear - in general You need a separate command pool for each thread; it's not just fancy recommendation, unless You want to perform full synchronization of recording command buffers on Your own).

Comment: I checked it on my other PC and it's exactly the same. About command pools:: each thread have their own (multi thread usage is reported by validation layers). I will try to